# Bootstrap: -nav-fixed-top have display errors in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build an CV for myself and having the following error:

When I press a few times across the navbar, just smash that bar (in Chrome 31.0.1650.63, WIN7, and another Desktop WIN8) I get a display error: Parts of the bars are hidden, when I scroll or hover a button, they come back. I've tested it in FF 25.0.1 and IExplore 11.0.9600 and it worked like a charm :-)

Is this a bug in Chrome or did I mess it up?

This is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/3az9m/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation">
           <span>...</span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a>...</a></
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I have the same issue...

Comment: I'm now on Chrome 32.0.1700.107 and that seems to fix my issue.